# Are Darkwing Duck and Ducktales set in the same universe?

Tags: disney, ducktales, darkwing-duck

At a glance, the shows *Darkwing Duck* and *Ducktales* share the same universe, as Launchpad McQuack and Gizmo-Duck exist in both shows, with the same personalities.

However, to my recollection, no mention of Duckburg is ever made during Darkwing Duck, nor do Launchpad or Gizmo-Duck ever refer to any of their friends from Duckburg.

**Are *Darkwing Duck* and *Ducktales* set in the same universe?**

Comment: As we know, "Life is like a hurricane" there in, Duckburg.  Hurricanes are obviously a type of trouble.  We also know "When there's trouble you call D.W."  Since nobody calls D.W. to Duckburg for everyday life, we can therefore prove that they are in two different universes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the creator of Darkwing Duck, [Tad Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tad_Stones), the show exists within an alternate universe from Duck Tales.

> *He goes on to state that though Launchpad first appeared in DuckTales, the Darkwing version was different. For starters, Launchpad always seemed to crash his plane in DuckTales but was a competent pilot in Darkwing Duck*
>
> ***"Because Launchpad appeared in DuckTales and we used Roboduck as the Superman character, the hero who gets all the glory as opposed to Darkwing, fans try to connect the two realities. They are two different universes in my book. We work in the alternate Duckiverse," says Stones.***
>
> *But that allowed Darkwing to do things a show today might be too afraid to — ignore its own past for the benefit of a specific episode. That happened with its most popular villain, Negaduck, who was introduced as an evil mirror to Darkwing. There was also a goody-goody mirror to Darkwing that the writers didn't like and didn't want to bring back. Stones told the writers just to bring back Negaduck and forget about the other version, and later they even ignored the original Negaduck origin, saying he comes from an alternate, evil universe.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Story of 'Darkwing Duck': The Cartoon with Heart That Brought "People Near Tears"](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/darkwing-duck-cartoon-heart-brought-927188)</sup></sub>

Comment: Huh. I do remember being confused about Negaduck. I thought I must have missed some connecting episode that explained how he got split off again, this time without resulting in a useless goody-two-shoes Drake half.

Answer (score 8):

In the rebooted Disney XD series, [they are now in the same universe](http://tvline.com/2017/08/11/ducktales-revival-preview-huey-dewey-louie-parents-interview/)

> “Darkwing Duck exists in this universe, which means he exists in our show,” Schwartz notes. “We don’t know what his presence will be, but we do have the ability to put [him in it]. And if you have Darkwing Duck, you may also be able to have characters from Goof Troop. We don’t know who! Once we start playing with the shows from the Disney Afternoon and all the characters in the Disney gauntlet… Let’s just say that anything you’ve seen in the old show, anything you’ve seen from that universe, if it’s possible to put it in, Frank [Angones] and Matt [Youngberg] will try to find a way to do so.”

Comment: While this information appears to be correct and is useful, the original question was asked before the existence of the rebooted series, and was asking about the original series.

Comment: I understand that. It's simply an interesting turn

Comment: What about Donald Duck's alter-ego, a superhero called Duck Avenger (Paperinik).

Answer (score 3):

In the new Duck Tales show, Darkwing Duck is a fictional TV show

However, the city of St. Canard does exist - it is mentioned in the first episode.

They have announced a crossover with Tale Spin - [Don Karnage is slated to appear](https://www.cbr.com/ducktales-don-karnage-talespin-appearance/)

[image]

Comment: The video is broken

Answer (score 2):

### Ducktales and Darkwing Duck have appeared in one crossover comic - but it was stricken from canon.

However, it isn't clear whether the reason it was struck from canon is due to the crossover being noncanonical, or due to Disney's dislike of the finished product. 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, and it has finally officially been confirmed in-universe!

Watch the new [Duck Tales promo](https://mobile.twitter.com/DuckTales/status/987768055970369538/video/1) released yesterday:
(Will replace with YouTube when available)

[image]

Comment: Given that there are parody My-Little-Pony lookalikes, how certain are you that this isn't a parody Darkwing Duck lookalike?

Comment: @Valorum From Machivity's answer. I just wanted to point out it finally was confirmed in-universe - the first ever Ducktales sighting!

Comment: I'm not seeing any confirmation that this is actually Darkwing Duck and not someone else who simply dresses like him.

Comment: @Valorum because the creators say he will appear.

Comment: Do they? **Where** do they say that?

Comment: @Valorum " which means he exists in our show" from the previous answer.

Comment: That should be in *your* answer. I didn't realise it related to the same show

Comment: This is for the rebooted universe? While this is informative, the question predates the existence of the reboot and was asking about the original shows.

Comment: @phantom42 yes. I do know that the original show they were not in the same universe, though now they may decide to retcon that they were.

Answer (score -1):

The old Darkwing and DuckTales were definitely in the same universe. Tad Stones is wrong.

I clearly remember Fenton Crackshell being in Darkwing, as was an image of Scrooge McDuck.

Here is the proof:

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Just because some characters are in both doesn't mean they take place in the same universe; just look at all the various Marvel universes for example.  To show they are in the same universe you should demonstrate the _places_ and _history_ are common.

Comment: To add to the previous comment could you also [edit] the evidence into your answer directly? The YouTube video could be taken down or the link rot and that would leave your answer being a bit lackluster. It is a lot better to include the evidence directly in your answer.

Comment: As quoted in the currently accepted answer, Tad Stones *specifically mentioned* that there are characters that appear in both shows, so using that as an argument that he's wrong just doesn't work, I'm afraid.