# In what issue can you find the Duck Avenger Robot and see its interior?

Tags: ducktales, darkwing-duck

As a kid I loved tinkering with things, I have a vivid image from reading *Duck Avenger* (or *Stål-Kalle* as it was called in Sweden, the original name of the comic is *Paperinik* and of Italian origin). He's in this robot/exo-skeleton and you have full view of all of the different buttons and gadgets and tinker-goodness.

Does anyone know what issue this appears in? I've been searching like a maniac for years to find it but to no avail.

**In what issue can you find the Duck Avenger Robot and see its interior?**

Comment: About the tags: "Paperinik/Duck Avenger" and "Darkwing Duck" are different characters, and they don't live in the DuckTales universe (see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140245/are-darkwing-duck-and-ducktales-set-in-the-same-universe )

Answer (score 7):

Could you be referring to [PKNA #6: Spores](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/PKNA_6:_Spores)? It features a robotic exo-skeleton and Duck Avenger being shown how to operate it.

[image][image]

Comment: Funny thing, he screams "GOOO!" even in the original Italian. By the way, he operates a big mecha also in "PKNA#10: Trauma", but there's no full view of the console, so I think Valorum is right and "PKNA #6: Spores" is the issue you're looking for.