# Does Mickey Mouse exist in the Ducktales universe (Or even the general Duckverse)?

Tags: ducktales, donald-duck, mickey-mouse

Does Mickey Mouse exist in the *DuckTales* universe? (or even the general Duckverse). I don't mean hidden Mickeys or cameos, I mean referenced in a way that acknowledges his existence.

Both television series and comics are canon.

Comment: He plays the role of God.

Comment: Does the [Lustiges Taschenbuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustiges_Taschenbuch) count as canon? The very old stories (~1970) had some meetings between the characters.

Comment: @Zommuter: I came here to ask the same thing. I lost a bet to a German friend a few years ago, thinking that Donald Duck and Mickey never met. Not just on cover (https://www.lustiges-taschenbuch.de/sites/default/files/cover/ltb-weihnachten-in-entenhausen_11.jpg), but I cannot find any reference for the story in which they do meet. The book came much later than 1970, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Related question about Ducktales and Darkwing Duck: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140245/are-darkwing-duck-and-ducktales-set-in-the-same-universe

Comment: @Zommuter If it's a duck based universe, I would think so. It's only the obvious non-duckverse stories that I wouldn't accept.

Comment: @Zommuter What makes that hard to answer is that Ducktales has a specific universe (where the events are self-contained), but the characters are not exclusive to that. For instance, I found [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/putan.jpg) for another question. We see Scrooge, Donald, Della (Donald's sister) and the nephews. Della is in the reboot universe. But we also see Daisy Duck, who is not part of the Ducktales universe in any iteration. The story told there appears to be unique to that one issue.

Comment: +1 for using the word "Duckverse"

Comment: @Machavity I always included the Duckverse in the question (see the edit history). I merely updated the question title to reflect that, as was requested in the comments to my answer.

Comment: Full list of Mickey Mouse - Donald Duck comics: https://inducks.org/comp2.php?code=&keyw=&keywt=i&exactpg=&pg1=&pg2=&bro2=&bro3=&exactparts=&parts1=&parts2=&kind=n&rowsperpage=0&columnsperpage=0&hero=&xapp=donald%2Cmickey&univ=&xa2=&creat=&creat2=Don+Rosa&plot=&plot2=&writ=&writ2=&art=&art2=&ink=&ink2=&excludeCZ=on&pub1=&pub2=&ser=&xref=&mref=&xrefd=&repabb=&repabbc=za&reppub1=&reppub2=&imgmode=0&vdesc2=on&vdesc=en&vdz=on&vca=on&vfr=on&vma=on&sort1=auto No clue how much are canon though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Not officially, no. In fact, Disney has a strict policy of not including him in any of the Ducktales universe. The current Disney XD reboot wanted to cross that line but the producer, Frank Angones, [was told no](https://suspendersofdisbelief.tumblr.com/post/155311728751/why-cant-you-have-mickey-in-duck-tales)

> > Why can't you have Mickey in Duck Tales?
>
> He’s way above my pay grade. I had one story that involved him and one that mentioned him, but both were vetoed.

In the reboot episode [Moonvasion!](https://ducktales.fandom.com/wiki/Moonvasion!), Donald is stranded on a desert island. In a Disney twist on the movie [Cast Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_Away), Donald's version of [Wilson the Volleyball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_Away#/media/File:Wilson_The_Volleyball.jpg) (Hanks' companion in his isolation) is a melon that looks and talks like Mickey (although only Donald can hear the Mickey voice). The melon is later eaten.

[image]

Comment: +1, but canon-wise, that's weird. Donald Duck knows both Mickey Mouse and Scrooge McDuck (at least in the new cartoon). So, two parallel universes with the same Donald Duck?

Comment: @phyrfox Ducktales has always been its own universe, separate from the "general Disney" universe, where Donald, Goofy, Pluto and Mickey all exist together.

Comment: @phyrfox compare and contrast: Marvel Cinematic Universe is also separate from other Marvel content, no mention of x-men for copyright reasons...

Comment: Totally makes more sense now. I've learnt something new today :D

Comment: Just to make things weirder, Scrooge McDuck does show up in *Kingdom Hearts,* along with Huey, Dewey, and Louie.  Donald is a main character in there, and King Mickey is a major supporting character.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Sure, but *Kingdom Hearts* canonically mashes up separate independent canons. That’s actually kind of its primary raison d'être.

Comment: If you really want a crossover(literally), [Mickey Mouse does cover that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-pqP_9r55E) (complete with nephews and Scrooge)

Comment: What happens in Ducksburg, stays in Ducksburg it seems.

Comment: I.E. the shareholders (led by the Disney family) said no :)

Comment: Goofy makes an appearance in the DuckTales reboot S3 episode "Quack Pack!"

Answer (score 24):

### He does not appear in the Ducktales Universe, but he does appear in the general Duckverse (Carl Barks, Don Rosa etc) at least once - in an unfinished Don Rosa comic.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Don Rosa always drew the Duckverse cartoons in a different universe than Mickey (as far as I know). The above comic is the one exception I'm aware of. Since it was never published in America, I'm not sure if its part of Duck cannon. If there are any other examples please add them. (Interestingly, this is the one Disney comic I've ever seen that acknowledges the existence of the Loony Toons universe - i.e, Daffy Duck.

Comment: This is not part of the Ducktales canon. Don Rosa's comics were part of the Carl Barks canon with a few sidesteps.

Comment: @Relix I clearly state "In the general Duckverse"

Comment: @TheAsh You should probably edit the question title since it still refers to DuckTales specifically

Comment: @Cubic Your right, and I fixed that.

Comment: Love the map of the Studios. This is pre-Tower of Terror, even -- and the only things on it that are still around are Star Tours, Backlot Express, Indiana Jones Stunt Spectacular, Gerties "Ice Cream of Extinction", and Min and Bill's Dockside Diner. Everything else is gone or repurposed. Well, except for the areas generically labeled "restaurants".

Answer (score 5):

> Does Mickey Mouse exist in the DuckTales universe? (or even the general Duckverse).

It's a bit complicated, here. First problem, there are many different universes/continuties in Disney; second you want to know about the existance, not the appearance, which is a detail that the current accepted answer fails to aknowledge.

The easiest bit of knowledge is the fact that Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck, in the "main Disney continuity" (usually referred as Mouseverse) are close friends. Actually in the main continuity all of the Disney comic characters exist, and crossovers are not so infrequent.

Outside of the main continuity the pairing of at least Mickey and Donald is a very common event: they have shared comic adventures, been together in countless movies (which are often "canon" and referenced decades later), videogames, and so on. The same applies to a plethora of other characters, even if it's a little less common.

So, in general we can sum it up to:

- The Mouseverse (the main Disney universe) contains every Disney comic character in a shared environment.
- Most of the time, in alternate universes Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck are shown together.
- In the DuckTales universe there is no mention of Mickey Mouse, but that doesn't mean he doesn't exist, simply he doesn't appear. Given all the above there could be good chances that he is there, but simply is not shown. Keep in mind for example that the original DuckTales contained The Phantom Blot, one of Mickey Mouse's traditional enemies...

Comment: If I can find some time, I'll try to add some links and sources to the answer.